# windows installer dont show ssd

Tags: windows, installation, solid-state-drive, diskpart

I tried to install a Linux OS on my laptop, to do this I formatted the hole SSD in my laptop. Now I want to switch back to windows. But the Windows installer doesn't show my SSD to install it there. If I go into the commando prop in the windows repair setting and execute the command disk part, it don't list my SSD. Does anyone have any Suggestion for the next step?

Thanks for any useful comments.
I have tried to format the disk with diskpart.

Comment: you'd better ask this on SuperUser, because SO is related to coding questions